# apache lang3:3.9 RandomStringUtils strange behaviour with regex

Tags: java, regex, apache-commons-lang3

I got strange behaviour from `apache.commons.lang3:3.9` (but everything is ok in 3.5).

I use `RandomStringUtils.random` to generate string with length 350. And it matches regex (that has 300 limit).

I can't see any special symbols generated in this string. And string.length() is 350.

```java
public class RegexCheck {
    private String VALUE_REGEXP = "^.{1,300}$";
    private String value= RandomStringUtils.random(350);

    public void run(){
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println("string length is " + value.length());
        if(value.matches(VALUE_REGEXP)){
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>match");
        }else{
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>don't match");
        }
    }
}
```

CodePoints in value:

for lang3:3.9: codePointCount is 197.
for lang3:3.5: codePointCount is 293. 
This values may vary from run-to-run.

Comment: I bet there are at least 50 characters from the [Unicode Supplementary Planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)). If I'm right, then `value.  codePointCount(0, value.length)` returns a value of 300 or less. Regex matches *Unicode Characters* (aka Code Points), not UTF-16 `char` values. Each Unicode Character from a Supplementary Plane is encoded as 2 Surrogate Characters in Java strings.

Comment: Actually, `.` in a Java regex only matches *bytes*, not code points. To match a code point, one would use `(?:\P{M}\p{M}*+)`

Comment: for lang3:3.9:  codePointCount is 197. But 
for lang3:3.5:  codePointCount is 293. 
This values may vary from run-to-run.